# air vent on downstairs bathroom but not upstairs

Tags: bathroom, vent

Is it true that downstairs bathroom "need ventilation" more than upstairs, to avoid mold growth?  I know at my house the downstairs bathroom has a vent fan but the upstairs does not.  I'm wondering if there's a reason for this, and also wondering if I need to add some ventilation to my downstairs bathrooms but not upstairs ones at a 4plex (these bathrooms do have windows).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Code any bathroom without a window needs a vent.  I would add a vent to every full bathroom though.  You dont want to open window in negative degree weather.